# Problems in extracting images from bag file

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm a newbie to ROS (and Linux too) so probably this is the most stupid question ever, but I swear I have followed the first tutorials on the wiki and I'm starting to learn little by little.
I have downloaded a bag file (named carrello1.bag) which contains a lot of topic, including some images that I need to extract in order to process them with some image processing programs.

I've seen the tutorial "export image and video data from a bag file" that is literally the thing I have to do, and I setup my system doing all the Beginner Level Tutorials and creating a new package (provatesi) with the launch file (named provatesi.launch) -  as in the tutorial and changing the directory

```
$(find image_view)/test.bag
```

to

```
~ /home/mattia/Desktop/carrello1.bag
```

since the tutorial assumes that *you have a .bag file previously created that is named test.bag and that this bag file is stored in the image_view package directory.*
But when I execute

```
$ roslaunch provatesi provatesi.launch
```

I get:

```
[FATAL] [1268662434.297981030]: Error opening file: ~/home/mattia/Desktop/carrello1.bag
```

Where am I making the mistake?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333148/problems-in-extracting-images-from-bag-file/) by [nujdilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/45681/nujdilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're passing a path that is not an absolute path. See #q331346 for a related question.

---

To be precise, there are two issues here:

1. `~/home/mattia/..` is not a valid path: `~` already evaluates to `/home/mattia`, so this would evaluate to `/home/mattia/home/mattia`.
2. `~` is evaluated (ie: replaced) by the shell (ie: `bash`), not `roslaunch`. So `roslaunch` doesn't do anything with it and passes the path directly to whatever tool/node/script it is that you're trying to start. As `~` is not a valid path, it will fail to open it (as evidenced by the "Error opening file" that you see).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nujdilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/45681/nujdilla/) on 2019-09-16**:
Thank you! .
Now that I corrected that, I have another type of error:

```
REQUIRED process [rosbag-2] has died!
```

This is my launch file

```
 <launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" required="true" args="/home/mattia/Desktop/carrello1.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" required="true" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/home/mattia/Desktop/camera"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-16**:
@nujdilla Since you have a new problem, you should probably open a new question

**Comment by [nujdilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/45681/nujdilla/) on 2019-09-17**:
I found the problem: the "to=" argument was wrong: it has to be the topic of the bag that contains the images. I have just finished successfully in extracting the images.
Thank you nonetheless!